# how to convert sql query with inner join to linq lambda expression?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

i want to select some fields from some tables 
please help to convert sql query to linq , i need to show these values into mvc3 webgrid.

How to convert inner join into linq? Or is there any way to do it in EF?

```
SELECT
DISTINCT
    SecurityIdentifier_All.SecurityId,
    NAV.CompanyName,
    NAV.SecurityType,
    SecurityIdentifier_All.Identifier,
    SecurityIdentifier_All.SecurityIdentifierTypeId
FROM
    Fireball_Reporting..Reporting_DailyNAV_Pricing NAV
INNER JOIN
    Fireball_Reporting..SecurityIdentifier_All ON  
         SecurityIdentifier_All.SecurityId = NAV.PricingSecurityID
inner join  
    (
    SELECT  SecurityId, MAX(SecurityIdentifierTypeId) SecurityIdentifierTypeId
FROM    Fireball_Reporting..SecurityIdentifier_All
where  SecurityIdentifierTypeId in (1,16)
group by SecurityId
    ) IdentifierType on
    IdentifierType.SecurityId = SecurityIdentifier_All.SecurityId and
    IdentifierType .SecurityIdentifierTypeId = 

SecurityIdentifier_All.SecurityIdentifierTypeId
WHERE
    Date = Fireball_Configuration.dbo.PreviousBusinessDay()
```

In above `SecurityIdentifier_All` and `NAV` is an view.
Fireball_Reporting database name.
In Answer till 1st inner join it is done. please help me to complete last section.

Comment: Your query is far too complex. You don't expect someone to do all this work? Please simplify.

Answer (score 0):

My original answer satisfied the previous version of your question, that included a SQL query with only two joins.

Now that you have three INNER JOINS, I wouldn't try to do all of that in one LINQ query.  You certainly could, but it would not be very readable (much like your SQL version).

I would do the subquery in a separate step.  Something like this:

```
var identifierType = context.SecurityIdentifier_Alls
    .Where(si => si.SecurityIdentifierTypeId == 1 || si.SecurityIdentifierTypeId == 6)
    .GroupBy(si => si.SecurityId)
    .Select(g => new { SecurityId = g.Key, SecurityIdentifierTypeField = g.Max(si => si.SecurityIdentifierTypeId) });

var query = 
    (from nav in context.Reporting_DailyNAV_Pricings
     from si in context.SecurityIdentifier_Alls
     from idt in identifierTypes 
     where si.SecurityId = nav.PricingSecurityID
        && idt.SecurityId == si.SecurityId
     select new { si.SecurityId, nav.CompanyName, nav.SecurityType, si.Identifier, si.SecurityIdentifierTypeId })
     .Distinct();
```

I didn't work in the UDF to get the previous business day.  Also, none of this is tested (of course), but this may be *close* to what you're looking for.

I'm not sure what you have available to you.  If you're using LINQ-to-Entities with navigation properties set up, it would eliminate having to link up the tables in the where clause in the code above.

Comment: need to do inner join plz help
INNER JOIN
Fireball_Reporting..SecurityIdentifier_All ON  
SecurityIdentifier_All.SecurityId = NAV.PricingSecurityID
inner join  
(
SELECT  SecurityId, MAX(SecurityIdentifierTypeId) SecurityIdentifierTypeId
FROM    Fireball_Reporting..SecurityIdentifier_All
where  SecurityIdentifierTypeId in (1,16)
group by SecurityId
) IdentifierType on
IdentifierType.SecurityId = SecurityIdentifier_All.SecurityId and
IdentifierType .SecurityIdentifierTypeId = 
SecurityIdentifier_All.SecurityIdentifierTypeId
WHERE
Date = Fireball_Configuration.dbo.PreviousBusinessDay()

Comment: I added some more code -- your updated question is much more complicated than the one I originally answered. This is about as far as I can take it. Good luck to you!